# Career options for current situation

Tags: career-development

After a few months working in a company as junior developer I was asked to leave. I ended up in test automation position of big company dealing with complex legacy java system using outdated testing tools. I had depression, sleep deprivation that added to excessive amount of stress in workplace. I tried to hide it because of fear loosing the job. As the result I undermined my health, stayed quiet, avoided social interactions and did not make any connections with other people that are working in the same open space. The first impression is made and hard to change. How?  I think current technical experience will not be valuable outside of the company. Having no any other job offer at the moment the jump to other company is not an option. Salary is more than I would get as junior developer because of the position of the company on the market. I am in my mid 20's and not sure if IT is the best deal for me because of my high sensitivity to stressful environment and my undeveloped social skills. I have cs degree and some skills building software. I have to pay bills or  quit. I am depressed and demotivated.

I need to recover health, save career opportunities (put on hold?), develop social skills, find the right place in IT.

Current position gives too much stress on my physical and mental health. It provides outdated and unrelated(?) to development experience. Switching with this experience to development after a year may be impossible? [I don't want to be stuck! There was an advice not to get into testing unless one really like it.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36300/how-do-i-avoid-getting-stuck-in-a-testing-position-for-the-rest-of-my-career) It's definitely not for me. The income is good in short term but way less in long term I think.

How can it impact my career if I will quit the job due to unable to cope with work tasks because of stress and derived health issued and questionable experience? How can I explain changing 1 job in such a short amount of time and quitting current one while on trial? What would be best for me and career in future?

Answer (score 0):

First impressions may be made, but they need not stick. When emotions are as deeply involved in your situation as yours are, you might try to change just one thing instead of trying to change everything.

You can choose now to begin building connections with coworkers. They don't bite. They might wonder what finally woke up the "quiet guy," but probably not. They're more likely to respond to you and bring you into their conversations.

Testing may not be for you, but in the short term, you can look to see what you can learn while you're doing it.

Also, don't beat yourself up over the loss of your previous job. Look at the reasons they gave for asking you to leave. What can you learn from that feedback? Is there anything you can do where you are now?

Just remember, you can change. You can make things better.

Please forgive the book plug (I have no motive other than to help you), you should consider reading [Do Over](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591847613), by Jon Acuff. I have been reading it because I needed an attitude adjustment.  His ideas have been helpful to me.